Does Poincare recurrence contradict that the Gibbs entropy is strictly increasing?
I've also posted this question on physics stack https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/827328/edit for reference.
Statistical Mechanics setup: Consider a box of gas with $N$ particles in some initial macro state (fixed temperature, energy, etc.). A configuration of particles giving a fixed macro state is called a micro state corresponding to that macro state, and the set of all micro states is called the phase space, and this is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$. The points in phase space are microstates. A macro state can also be seen as a probability distribution on phase space. If $\mu$ is a macro state and $x$ is a microstate with $\mu(\{x\})>0$, then $x$ is a microstate corresponding to the macro state $\mu$. Because a single micro state can only correspond to one macro state, if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are two macro states (measures on phase space), then $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are disjointly supported. Then entropy of a macro state $\mu$ is given by $E(\mu)=\sum_n \mu(\{x_n\})ln(\frac{1}{\mu(\{x_n\})})$. Since this Gibbs entropy is only defined for discrete probability distributions, this is why we assumed phase space is discrete.
Poincare Recurrence: Now, If $T:\mathbb{R}^{6N}\to \mathbb{R}^{6N}$ is the time evolution of phase space, then by the Poincare recurrence theorem, for any set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^{6n}$, the set of points in $A$ that return to $A$ infinitely often has measure $\mu(A)$, where here $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$. So if the system is initially in some state, with corresponding microstate $x$, then there is a sequence $(n_k)_k$ of natural numbers such that $d(T^{n_k}x,x)\to 0$. See for example, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/145005/poincare-recurrence-theorem-and-convergence-on-compact-metric-spaces. Now, I've seen it claimed that in Huang's Statistical Mechanics book that the Poincare recurrence theorem contradicts that the Gibbs entropy is strictly increasing in time. Intuitively, one starts with a macro state and a corresponding micro state, eventually that micro state is arbitrarily close the original one, so the entropy should be get closer to the original value, and so it can't be strictly increasing.
My question is, does this actually contradict that Gibbs entropy is strictly increasing? For one, it could be that $T^{n_k}x$ just stays in the same macro state as $x$ for all $k$,in which case, the entropy remains constant. It could also be that $T^nx$ leaves the macro state that $x$ is in, for some $n$, and doesn't actually return to it, even if it approaches the original macro state (the original macro state could just be a dirac measure on $\{x\}$, for example). The other thing is that there is not even a guarantee that there is any $x$ for which $d(T^{n_k}x,x)\to 0$, since phase space is a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^{6N}$ and therefore has measure zero. So I'm not sure if I have something wrong with the formalism, or I'm not understanding how to apply the Poincare recurrence theorem in this situation, but it doesn't seem like a contraction.

Are we talking about mathematics or physics? In mathematics the entropy can only be computed for an invariant measure $\mu$, and doesn't change with time. Incidentally, the phase space need not be "discrete" (take for example a geodesic flow on a compact space with respect to the Liouville measure).

By entropy, I mean the Gibbs/Shannon functional of a discrete probability distribution. This is why I assumed phase space was discrete. I suppose you could replace the sum with an integral, but then that's not the same notion of entropy from statistical mechanics.

If the distribution does not change, then I'm confused as to what it means for entropy to ever increase, since Gibbs entropy is a function of the distribution itself. Do you mean that the macro states correspond precisely to the T-invariant measures on phase space, and the entropy of a state is precisely the entropy of one of these measures?

I regret that I am not able to follow the physics language that you use, sorry. In mathematics there is not concept of entropy that changes with time. So probably you are talking about something else but I don't know what it can be.

@JohnB No worries. I appreciate your thoughts. By time, I mean successive iterates of the mapping $T$ on phase space that perseveres Lebesgue measure, but perhaps it is not meaningful and I need to consider it further. I appreciate your comment.
